# Wordpress search query posts

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am developing custom search for my wordpress website...
http://www.nekretnine-oglasi.me/ here is website and you can see that most fields are custom fields except 'Kategorija' which is category and 'Grad' which is post_title..

Here is my query:

```
query_posts(array(
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'category_name' => $_POST['kategorija'],
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_title' => $_POST['grad'] //This line doesnt work
)
```

Primary is to make 'post_title' to work...

And then to make other custom fields to work...

With this query I get posts from category but not from category and post_title.

Comment: `post_title` is not a option in `query_post`. You should work with `add_filter` for filtering post titles.

Comment: How to do that... can you send me some example
?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this solution you should define a filter on the posts_where attribute in the wp_query.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18703/wp-query-with-post-title-like-something

With this code you can define a custom SQL where statement:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse18703_posts_where', 10, 2 );
function wpse18703_posts_where( $where, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $wpse18703_title = $wp_query->get( 'wpse18703_title' ) ) {
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'' . esc_sql( $wpdb->esc_like( $wpse18703_title ) ) . '%\'';
    }
    return $where;
}
```

And you can use in the query like this one:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'     => 'date',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'wpse18703_title' => $_POST['grad']
  );
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

I couldn't try out the code snippets, but i my opinion it's a good for a starter guide.